# Greek philosophy: Why would Finite Time weaken the forces of evil?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-religion, presocratics

The inspiration for this question is the metaphysics of evil in [Zurvanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zurvanism), however, I do not want to use the internal logic of this religious system to understand this topic, rather I want to see if there is anything from the philosophy from the pre-socratics or later on in the School of Athens that addresses the power of evil with relation to time.

Here is relevant commentary by Zaehner, who has among the most widely cited works on the topic:

> The fact that Ahriman is finally defeated in the cosmic battle
> reflects no credit on Time: it is due rather to the very nature of
> Ahriman himself, whose 'powerlessness, self-will, imperfection, and
> slowness in knowledge'' become manifest as soon as finite Time comes
> into operation. Without finite Time these would merely have been
> potential, and the wickedness of Ahriman could never have been
> destroyed. Once the perfection and wisdom of Ohrmazd can come into
> operation through Time, the destruction of Ahriman, whose nature is
> chaotically destructive, is assured.

What is notable to me is that there is a core belief that good will win over evil, but the good is not omnipotent; the good cannot purge the cosmos of (the potentiality of) evil when in a state of Infinite Time. It is only under a setting of Finite Time that it becomes possible to thwart evil, because, as Zaehner describes, Finite Time exposes the 'powerlessness' and 'slowness in knowledge' of the Evil One.

For the uninitiated, applying a Greek philosophic lens to this topic may seem arbitrary, however, there is reason to think that Zurvanism did draw from Greek thinking. The following is not particularly relevant to the question, but it may help in bringing into focus the intellectual climate of this time period and region (also from Zaehner):

> That the Pahlavi books borrow extensively from Greek philosophy seems
> now indisputable. The Sassanian Empire is no exception to the general
> rule that the inferior civilization is prone to borrow from the
> superior.

### Question

Is there anything in the Greek philosophic schools (presocratics-School of Athens) that addresses the potency of evil as a function of time? It doesn't have to totally agree with the above logic, just as long as it involves time as a determinative factor for its discussion on evil.